# Any counter example for this: ${\phi(2^n-1)} \bmod \tau(2^n-1)=0$ for every integer $n \geq 1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, conjectures, infinite-divisibility

I asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2005633/156150) In S.E but i don't received any resposnes for it, I would like to know if it is appropriate for M.O.

I'm always interesting for properties  of the following series : $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\tau(2^n-1)}{\phi(2^n-1)}$  such that: $\tau(N)$ is the number of divisors of $N$  and $\phi$ is Euler totient function, In this question i w'd be interest to know a little bit about the reciprocal of each term of the titled series at $N=2^n-1$ for every $n\geq 1$.

**Note:01** According to my calculations that i run in wolfram alpha from $n=1$ to $100$ I have got this result as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%20of[%20phi%282%5En-1%29%20mod%20%28tau%282%5En-1%29%29],n%3D1%20to%20100) such that it works which letting me to ask the following question.

**My question here is:**  Is ${\tau(2^n-1)}$ always  divides $\phi(2^n-1)$  for every integer $n\geq 1$ and any counterexample for it?

Thank you for any help !!!

Comment: The smallest counterexample occurs at $n=253$.

Comment: If odd $m$ is squarefree, say, $m=p_1p_2\cdots p_r$, then $\tau(m)=2^r$, and $$\phi(m)=2^r{p_1-1\over2}{p_2-1\over2}\cdots{p_r-1\over2}$$ so counterexamples can only occur when $2^n-1$ is not squarefree.

Comment: If $k$ is a square-free odd integer 
define $\omega(k)$ to be the l.c.m. of all the $\omega(p)$'s with $p|k$; thus $\omega(k)$ is the order of $2 \pmod{k^2}$.  

Note that $k^2$ divides $2^n-1$ if and only if $\omega(k)$ divides $n$.  Now note that $\omega(3)=6$, $\omega(5)=20$, $\omega(7)=21$, $\omega(11)=110$, $\omega(13)=156$ and so on.  Thus if $n$ is divisible by $6$, or $20$ or $21$, or $110$, or $156$ etc then $2^n-1$ is not squarefree  , for example $n=12$ is divisible by $6$ and here :${2}^{12}-1$ is  not counter example , how this ?

Comment: Crossosted at [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005633/is-tau2n-1-always-divides-phi2n-1-for-every-integer-n-geq-1).